# Объявления констант

Tags: c++

Чем отличаются

```
float i = 1.35f;
const float i = 1.35f;
```

?Заранее спасибо.

Comment: я думаю, что правильный ответ в том, что первое не является объявлением константы. (исходя из темы вопроса я предполагаю, что Автор вопроса считает и то, и другое объявлением констант).

Comment: @KoVadim любопытно, как первый вариант можно заподозрить в том, что это объявление константы?

Comment: Как можно заподозрить? легко, если в этом не разбираться. И как видно по комментарию @Rolton ниже - я не сильно далеко от правды.

Comment: @KoVadim я немного не  об этом. Здесь не очень понятен ход мыслей ТСа. Обычно при изучении C++ (как впрочем и любого другого языка) сначала изучают, что такое переменные, как в них записываются значения, и только потом - что такое константы, и зачем они нужны. Так вот тут напрашивается вопрос - если автор считает оба выражения объявлениями констант, то как тогда в его представлении выглядит работа с переменными?

Comment: есть разные книги и разные способы изучения. Некоторые программисты, разбираясь в дебрях некоторых технологий своего языка, могут абсолютно не знать базовых вещей. И я такое встречал.

А для ТС видимо объявление переменной - это только `int a;` А `int a = 10;` - это уже что то непонятное.

Comment: >А для ТС видимо объявление переменной - это только int a; А int a = 10

похоже на тяжелое наследие Турбо Паскаля)

Answer (score 4):

Тем, что во втором случае вы не сможете присвоить *i* другое значение.

P.S. Вы ведь и сами могли это проверить, и это заняло бы меньше времени, чем писать вопрос, так почему не сделали этого?

Comment: зачем тогда нужно float i = 1.35f f после значения 1.35?

Comment: @Rolton вас удивляет, что переменным можно присваивать значения? Поверьте, это не самое поразительное, чем вас может удивить C++

Comment: Буква "f" нужна для указания компилятору о типе литеральной константы "1.35" как float.

Answer (score 4):

Слово `const` говорит о том, что в дальнейшем нельзя будет менять знаечние этой переменной, в отличии от первой строки (где нет слова "const"), при использовании которой вы сможете использовать эту перемнную и менять ее значение.